# Images not uploading into assets

Tags: php, json, symfony, content-management-system, pimcore

When trying upload "drag & drop" image jpg at pimcore admin panel into assets this pops out:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
(1/1) NotEncodableValueException
```

Below is the error image

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look deep into screenshot you will find this line
***failed to open stream, permission denied.***

You can give permission like this

```
sudo chmod 777 -Rf /var/www/html/pimcore/web/var/assets/
```

Do let me know if it gets solved.